# Signing and verifying string signatures with RSA C#

Tags: c#, rsa, signing

I am trying to create a very basic mini-app for an uni project which signs the string written in WinForms textfield and then verifies it.

This is how the form looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzNul.jpg

The code:

```
    private void BtnEncrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

        string privateKey = RSA.ToXmlString(true);

        RSA.FromXmlString(privateKey);
        RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter RSAFormatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(RSA);
        RSAFormatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA1");
        SHA1Managed SHhash = new SHA1Managed();
        byte[] SignedHashValue = RSAFormatter.CreateSignature(SHhash.ComputeHash(new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(textboxplaintext.Text)));
        string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(SignedHashValue);
        textboxsigned.Text = signature;
    }
```

BtnEncrypt is the 'Sign' button, BtnDecrypt is the 'Verify' button, textboxplaintext is the first textfield, textboxsigned is the second textfield

```
    private void BtnDecrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        string publicKey = RSA.ToXmlString(false);
        RSA.FromXmlString(publicKey);
        RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter RSADeformatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter(RSA);
        RSADeformatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA1");
        SHA1Managed SHhash = new SHA1Managed();
        if (RSADeformatter.VerifySignature(SHhash.ComputeHash(new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(textboxsigned.Text)),
         Convert.FromBase64String(signature))           //the error displays here
         )
        {

            MessageBox.Show("The signature is valid.");
            /// The signature is valid.
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The signature is not valid.");
            /// The signature is not valid.
        }
    }
```

I am relatively new to this, so, i expect multiple mistakes. Any help would be great! Thank you

Comment: if you 'expect' mistakes, then you can try launching your code, get some of them, try find solution over the internet yourself and if nothing helps, ask StackOverflow.with mentioning error message.

Comment: @pwrigshihanomoronimo Hello, i apologize for not clarifying it enough. The only code error is at the 'Convert.FromBase64String(signature))' line, where 'signature' is supposed to be called from the other button but i am not sure how that is done.

Comment: You wrote string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(SignedHashValue) in first code, that means you converted your hashed byte array to Base64 format string, and in second code you should get it from Convert.FromBase64String(textboxsigned.Text)

Comment: @MajidKiani Hello, i've already tried that but it never validates the signature. It always outputs 'The signature is not valid'.